# Android Studio after deploying app not launching on Phone

Tags: android, android-studio

Got a new computer installed android studio. Created a test app (default) - No coding. I compiled and clicked the run and installed the app to the device (1+6). The app is installed but doesn't launch automatically.

I checked the configuration shows launch default activity.

[image: Configuration]

What could be wrong?

Also another strange thing: I get emulator-5556 [OFFLINE] - blinking always in select deployment target.

Can someone help me fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it. The problem seems to be the result of another program using the same port 5556.
In my case it was Videostream.[Videostream tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5zCS.png)

After ending the tasks related to Videostream the blinking stopped and apps were deployed normally.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case, you can do as follows

```
adb kill-server
adb reconnect
```

You should see online after above command & select this emulator from

```
- Run > Edit Configurations > Target 
In General Tabarea choose 
- Target: Emulator 
- Android Virtual Device: <your emulator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check launch options from Run/Debug Configuration.

Lunch options > Launch > select as default Activity

[image]

Happy coding !!!

Answer (score -1):

You need to select an emulator under **Deployment Target Options** -> **Target**:.

Comment: Done. Not working. I am talking about my device (oneplus 6)