# Why my android studio doesn't launch app automatically after install(run)

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I build and run my project by clicking the green arrow on android studio, my app should be launched automatically but it just installed then nothing happened.

I've tried reinstall android studio and create a new project but it still not fixed.

This is my Run/Debug configuration (Just the default setting).

[image]

This is the android manifest

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I found the error message as below, why it disconnects?

```
04/20 16:37:14: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t [my project path]\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk [my project path]\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk [my project path]\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk [my project path]\app\build\intermediates\resources\instant-run\debug\resources-debug.apk [my project path]\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk [my project path]\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk [my project path]\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk [my project path]\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk [my project path]\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk [my project path]\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk [my project path]\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk [my project path]\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk [my project path]\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
Device emulator-5556disconnected, monitoring stopped.
Split APKs installed in 1 s 572 ms
```

Comment: Check logcat. Maybe the app crashes immediately after installing and running.

Comment: please make it CHECK for Use same device for future launches then make it apply and then Ok then try to install may be it will work

Comment: does you StartingActivity is in Launcher Category?

Answer (score 6):

Lunch options > Launch > select as default Activity

[image]

Happy coding !!!

Answer (score 1):

It caused by chrome extension - VideoStream, it using the same port 5556 as adb. Just terminate or uninstall it then work fine.

ref.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54660175/4557420

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54731956/4557420